# DataMapper can't convert string to integer enum

Tags: ruby, datamapper, padrino

I have the following model

```
class TagType
  include DataMapper::Resource

  ## Relationships
  belongs_to :category
  has n, :tags

  ## Properties
  property :uuid, UUID, :key => true, :default => lambda { |r,p| SecureRandom.uuid }
  property :name, Enum[:venue, :format, :genre, :organization]
end
```

In my app controller, I receive a name parameter as a string, turn it into a symbol, and try to perform the lookup:

```
get ':cat_name/:tag_type' do
cat = Category.first :name => params[:cat_name]
halt 400, "Invalid category" if cat.nil?
sym = params[:tag_type].to_sym
puts "Sym: #{ sym.inspect }"
raise "Not symbol!" if sym.class != Symbol
tag_type = TagType.first(:category => cat, :name => sym)
halt 400, "Invalid tag type name" if tag_type.nil?
```

This is giving me

> 4) Error:
>   test_0001_should_get_all_the_tags_for_a_category(TagController):
>   TypeError: can't convert String into Integer
>       test/app/controllers/tag_controller_test.rb:10:in `[]'
>       test/app/controllers/tag_controller_test.rb:10:in`block (2 levels) in '

The output for `puts "Sym: #{ sym.inspect }"`  is  `Sym: :venue`
I have tried just putting a literal `:genre` in place of sym to ensure that works ok, and it does. I try to raise an exception if it's not a symbol, but this doesn't fire and every time, it ends up throwing this error despite it clearly being a symbol.

This is using the DataMapper extension `dm-types`, and more specifically the [Enum class](https://github.com/datamapper/dm-types/blob/master/lib/dm-types/enum.rb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at my exception, you'll see I missed a vital detail:

> ) Error:
>   test_0001_should_get_all_the_tags_for_a_category(TagController):
>   TypeError: can't convert String into Integer
>   test/app/controllers/tag_controller_test.rb:10:in []'
>   **test**/app/controllers/tag_controller_test.rb:10:inblock (2 levels) in

This was on line 10 of my test which happened to match up with the line in the app controller itself! DataMapper is working fine. My fault.